# javascript object in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Lambda and creating method by using node.js.

I need an object like this:

```
[
 {

        "TeamName" : "Sales",
        "2020-01-01": "90",
        "2020-01-02": "92",
        "2020-01-03": "95",
        "2020-01-04": "90",
        "2020-01-05": "56",
        "2020-01-06": "70",
        "2020-01-07": "73"
    },
]
```

but my current response is this:

```
[

 {

    "TeamName": "Billing",
    "DateTime": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Score": 9
  },

  {

    "TeamName": "Billing",
    "DateTime": "2020-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Score": 9
  },
{

    "TeamName": "Billing",
    "DateTime": "2020-06-11T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Score": 5
  },
]
```

Here is my Lambda method. I am not good at creating javascript object so please help me to make a response like this, Thanks.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Events:',event);
  let UserHierarchyGroupID = event['hierarchyGroupId'];
  let team = [];
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let sql = `SELECT date(Feedback.DateTime) as datetime,Feedback.Score,UserHierarchy.Layer5
               FROM ctrData2.Feedback
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.CallDetail ON CallDetail.ContactId = Feedback.FeedbackID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.UserTable ON UserTable.UserID = CallDetail.UserID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ctrData2.UserHierarchy ON UserTable.UserID  = UserHierarchy.UserID
               WHERE UserTable.UserHierarchyGroupID=?`;
    let field = [UserHierarchyGroupID];
    connection.query(sql,field, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // console.log(result);
      connection.release();
      var date;
      var score;
    if(result.length>0){
           result.forEach((item)=>{
             team.push({
               "TeamName": item.Layer5,
               "DateTime": item.datetime,
               "Score": item.Score
               
             });
           });
           
      }else{
            callback(null,{
              status: 404,
              Body: "Not found"
            });
          }
      callback(null,team);
      // FomratObjects(result,(formattedResponse)=>{
      //   // console.log(formattedResponse);
      //   callback(formattedResponse);
      // });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want an output object like that? It looks more like CSV output than a JSON object. For example, JSON does not have the concept of a "header" or "columns".

Comment: yes i am sure i want an output object like that. its a company requirement

Comment: I think after you have got your object like you are getting it now you have to process it further to get the other object. Like first get the keys set and then loop through the keys and filter the records based on each key and then build the other object and push to an array.

Comment: What is the source of sales? is the score means sales? Are you adding all scores for each date to come up with that day sales?

Comment: score means feedback score. whats the feedback score customer gave to an agent. if you know how to make an object like that So, can you please create that for me and share a piece of code with me?

Comment: its a total number of score agent got on that date, we have to add the scores of same date and then display it against that date.@muasif80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its doesn't look possible to create an object exactly like you mentioned but you can do this to assign value to every single date.
Hope it will be helpful.

```
function formatData(data){
  var nObject = {};
  data.forEach(d=>{
    nObject[moment(d.datetime).format('MM-DD-YYYY')]=d.Score;
  });
  return nObject;
}
```